# Maximum Modulus Principle and proving that Re(f) does not achieve a local maximum

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, maximum-principle

Let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic and nonconstant function and $U$ be open.
I want to prove that $Re(f)$ does not achieve a local maximum on $U$.

I started by supposing for contradiction that $Re(f)$ has a local maximum and decomposing $f(z)=a+bi$.

Our claim then becomes: $ \exists z_{1}\in U$ where $f(z_{1})=a_{1}+b_{1}i$  such that $\forall z\in U, f(z)=a+bi$ we have $a_{1}\geq a$.

Now the Maximum Modulus principle applies and therefore $f(z)=|a+bi|$ has no local maximum. Therefore, $\exists z_{2}\in U$ such that $|f(z_{1})|=|a_{1}+b_{1}i|\leq|a_{2}+b_{2}i|=|f(z_{2})|$

But I am stuck, I don't know how to reach a contradiction from here.

Any suggestions? Should I go about it in another way?(although I am pretty sure I have to use the Maximum Modulus Principle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Examining the function 
$$
e^{f(z)},
$$
which is also analytic by hypothesis,
is a standard trick. Note that the modulus of an exponential comes from the real part of its argument.

Comment: do you mean utilizing the fact that $|e^{f(z)}|=|e^{a+bi}|=e^{a}$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the modulus signs. I don't understand your notation, what is $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Oh I see. So I think I have a plan: Apply max modulus principle on $e^{f(z)}$ conclude that $|e^{f(z)}|=e^{a(x,y)}$ has no local maximum, then how do I conclude that a(x,y) has no local maximum, I can't use the monotonicity of $e$ right? Or should I maybe suppose for contradiction that $a(x,y)$  has a local maximum and then take exponential of the maximum and compare to any other $z$, I will contradict the max modulus principle?

Comment: ouh ok! Thank you very much!!

Comment: does $e^a$ not achieving its maximum imply $a$ doesn't achieve its maximum? @operatorerror

Comment: yes, try the contrapositive and use that $e^x$ is increasing.